# ¿Por qué un contador entrega valores negativos?

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.lang.Math ;

public class PilaArena2 {

static public void main(String[] args) { 

    System.out.println("Valor de  N? : ");
    Scanner N = new Scanner(System.in);
    Double n = N.nextDouble();

    Ventana Dos = new Ventana(500,"Pila de Arena 2");

    double a =  Math.sqrt(n);
    int v = (int) (n+0);
    int b = (int) (a);

    if (b%2==0) {
        b=b+1;
    }
    System.out.println("Tamaño matriz: "+b+"x"+b);
    int k=0;

    int matrix2[][] = new int[b][b];
    matrix2[(b/2)][(b/2)]= v; 
    int corr=0;
    do {
        corr=0;
    for ( int j=0; j < b-1; j++ ) {
        for ( int i=0; i < b-1; i++ ) {
            if (matrix2[j][i] >3) {
                int f= matrix2[j][i];
                int g= f/4;

                matrix2[j][i+1] =matrix2[j][i+1] + g;
                matrix2[j][i-1] =matrix2[j][i-1] + g;
                matrix2[j+1][i] =matrix2[j+1][i] + g;
                matrix2[j-1][i] =matrix2[j-1][i] + g;
                matrix2[j][i]= f%4 ;
                k++;
                corr=1;

            }
        }
    }

    }while (corr == 1);

    System.out.println("Numero de iteraciones: "+k);
    Dos.mostrarMatriz(matrix2);
}
}
```

Lo que importa del código es la variable `iteraciones` que es la que arroja valores negativos, la idea es que al final del proceso (el cual corresponde a la distribución de granos de arena y del que borre parte del código ya que eso no era lo relevante) entregue la cantidad de veces que la variable `corr` cambió sus valores. Éste es un número grande por ello luego de probar con 600.000 granos de arena la variable `int` entrega valores negativos.

¿Por qué el contador entrega valores negativos? ¿cómo solucionarlo?

Comment: multiplicalo por -1 Solo si es < que 0 ..

Comment: sucede que si un contador te arroja valores negativos implica que superó la cantidad de valores que admite el programa y se devolvió( por así decirlo), por ello necesito saber la conversión, es decir, el valor máximo de un contador en java

Comment: ...y además, ¿dónde estás asignando un valor a `TamañoMatriz`? ¿cuántos valores estás manejando en el array? ¿qué hiciste para depurarlo? Al pie de tu pregunta está el enlace para **[edit]**, ¿podrías describir tu problema para alguien que no sabe qué estás intentando ni tiene una bola de cristal?

Comment: si `int` se queda sin espacio prueba `long`

Comment: en ese caso es mejor usar `Math.abs(value)`. Por otro lado, @SofíaBobadillaPonce tu pregunta esta muy mal formulada, necesitas explicar mejor tu problema (explicar en tu pregunta no en comentarios), casos de pruebas, que esperas recibir y cuales son los valores que estas obteniendo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> El porqué puede devolver un valor negativo.

El tipo de dato **int** es un entero de 32 bits. Tiene un valor mínimo de -2,147,483,648 (**0x80000000**) y un valor máximo de 2,147,483,647 (**0x7FFFFFFF**)

Entonces cuando agregas uno al valor máximo de un entero:

0x7FFFFFFF + 0x00000001 = 0x80000000 (-2,147,483,648)

> Cómo solucionarlo.

Si la cantidad de iteraciones que utilizas supera los 2,147,483,647 te recomiendo cambiar el tipo de dato "k" de **int** a **long**

Comment: Genial!, gracias por expicarlo :)

Answer (score 3):

En Java, el tipo primitivo `int` y su versión objeto `Integer` usan 4 bytes para guardar un número entero. Eso te da 2<sup>32</sup> valores distintos. Puesto que la mitad de esos valores son negativos mediante la notación [complemento a 2](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_a_dos), el máximo valor positivo que puedes guardar es **[2<sup>31</sup>-1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE)** (2.147.483.647), que es el valor de la constante `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Si a ese valor le sumas uno, provocas un [desbordamiento artimético](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_aritm%C3%A9tico) (*overflow*, en inglés)

Si necesitas valores más grandes, usa `long` en lugar de `int`, donde pasas a tener un límite de [2<sup>63</sup>-1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#MAX_VALUE) (9.223.372.036.854.775.807, más de 9 trillones), ya que se usan 8 bytes

Comment: Te agradezco enorme, esta era la info que necesitaba :)

Comment: Si te ha resultado útil, por favor, selecciona la respuesta como "aceptada" para que la pregunta se queda marcada como respondida